# SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file C:\Python36\python.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

> ```
> SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file
> C:\Python36\python.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared
> ```

I don't understand why it shows me that when I want to open the interpreter. Can someone help me please?

[image: snap shot]

Comment: can you please post your code, some sample input, expected output etc?

Comment: Sorry the image will not load but here's what the interpreter shows me :  Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:14:34) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  File "C:\Python36\python.exe", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file C:\Python36\python.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: I don't have code it shows me that when i want to open the interpreter

Comment: Can you show the command you used to start the interpreter?

Comment: @Beno please do NOT post images - copy-paste from your terminal instead.

Comment: I don't use command, I start the interpreter directly from my programs. For exemple : windows+R and I write python.exe and then it shows me : SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file C:\Python36\python.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared.

Comment: Not sure what's going on there, but I can reproduce that error by trying to run python.exe as a module from python.exe. In other words, by running `python.exe python.exe` from a command prompt. Windows may be confused and trying to do something similar.

Comment: (Not exactly the same, as I don't get the interpreter header. But the traceback is the same.)

Comment: Not on windows, so this is a wild, wild (wild) guess - Could you check `Control Panel \ System and Security \ System --> advanced --> environment variables` for `PYTHONSTARTUP`?

Comment: This happens when you type `python.exe python.exe` into a command prompt, it tries to read the binary executable file as UTF-8 source code, which fails. Double-check your terminal command!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got this error on running pyinstaller's exe file from cmd and it automatically got fixed when I ran that file by directly clicking on it NOT from cmd

So, to fix this problem don't run file from terminal/cmd, try any other way.

Comment: Note that this is because of Python's encoding language based on "unicode-escape" when ran on the terminal. The command-line utility changes this. Double click this from File Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's a wrong value for PYTHONSTARTUP which was asking me a problem. Thank you all !

Comment: Could you please provide what value PYTHONSTARTUP was and currently is?

Comment: @christopherson It is a file with code that will be executed on startup. I strongly suspect that it was set to `$env:PYTHONSTARTUP = "python.exe"`, try unsetting it with e.g. `$env:PYTHONSTARTUP = ""` in PowerShell