# SyntaxError when using pip on command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I hope you're doing good..
I am beginner to Python and I wanted to install/uninstall some packages using pip on command prompt using the pip command. But, whenever I run any command it throws an error.
For example when I try to print all the installed packages by typing **pip list**. It throws this error.

```
  File "C:\Users\iMacPro 2K19\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file C:\Users\iMacPro 2K19\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

I have visited the included webpage for a solution but wasn't able to get a straight and, i think, easy solution to the problem.. This error comes up every time i try to run any pip command. Any help will be appericiated.. Much thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092176/syntaxerror-non-utf-8-code-starting-with-x91

Comment: @101 I don’t think this applies here. This isn’t their own code.

Comment: It looks like your installation is corrupted. You may need to reinstall.

Comment: What is the value of your PYTHONSTARTUP variable?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393026/syntaxerror-non-utf-8-code-starting-with-x90-in-file-c-python36-python-exe) - it's probably the wrong value of PYTHONSTARTUP.